# automatic sign on for application

Tags: android, caching, cookies, authentication, remember-me

I'm trying to  find out the correct terminology for the feature that allows a user to login to an app an initial time, then if they open that same app later and their cookies have not expired it will automatically log them back in. I wanted to attempt some research before posting here, but I am unsure of how to phrase what I'm asking in the search engine. lol.

Any help is welcomed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Use a persistent cookie**:

This is
the easy solution. If you are
connecting to a web site, have
the server authenticate the user
the first time they log on, and
then set a persistent cookie on
the user's phone containing a
(cryptographically) random
128-bit string that is
associated with the user's
account. Every subsequent time
the user launches the
application, when it contacts
the server over HTTP/HTTPS,
the client will send its
persistent cookie, which the
server can use to authenticate
the client. Ideally, you'd use
HTTPS and use secure cookies.

**Use public key authentication.**:

This is the trickier solution.
You could have the phone
application generate its own
public/private keypair. When
the user logs on for the first
time, the application can send
the public key, and the server
can associate the public key
with that account. Every
subsequent time the user
launches the application, the
application can authenticate
itself to the server using the
private key.
For instance, if you are
using web technology, you
might have the client
generate a self-signed
cert, connect to the server
using HTTPS, and
authenticate itself using
its client cert. You would
have to test whether web
views on Android support
client certs well.
Alternatively, if you
connect to the server
using your own custom
protocol, tunnel it over
SSL or TLS, and use the
client certs feature of SSL/
TLS.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying I just need to write the cookie to a encrypted file on the sdcard, and during the OnResume() / OnStart() attempt to make a request using the stored cookies, and if it works it means the cookies are still valid; otherwise reauthenticate.

Comment: @snapplex - Depends on your server side logic.If they support server side session then you could take this way.

Comment: @snapplex - Here is one more way ...Upon succesful login the api has to give you a token and you can attach that as header field and server side has to allow the request as it is valid.The token can be designed to be valid untill the user changes the password.If user changes the password and your app uses the same token then API has to respond unAuthroised and you have to prompt user for username and password and use the reutrning Token.